# Head Pointer is changing with linked list items

Tags: c

This program is supposed to print new element and the start element. But the start element is getting changed every time I assign a new element. `init_class()` returns a pointer to class.

```
/*
  Class->Albert
            |
            V
         Einstein

*/


#include "datadef.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char Name[30][30];

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Incorrect number of arguments, please retry...\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    Class* classp;
    classp = init_class();

    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("File pointer allocation error...Ending the program..\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    int count = 0;
    Student* prevp;
    Student* currp;
    while(!feof(fp))
   {
        fscanf(fp,"%s",Name[count]);
        currp = init(Name[count]);
        if (!count)
        {
            classp->startp = currp;
            printf("Assigned the head pointer\n");
        }
        else
        {
            prevp->nextp = currp;
            printf("appending to the pre-existing list\n");
        }
        count+=1;
        prevp = currp;
        printf("Current : %s \n",currp->name);
        printf("Head : %s \n",classp->startp->name);
        printf("\n\n");
    }
```

Result:

> Assigned the head pointer
>
> Current : Albert
>
> Head : Albert
>
> appending to the pre-existing list
>
> Current : Einstein
>
> Head : Einstein

Expected result:

> Assigned the head pointer
>
> Current : Albert
>
> Head : Albert
>
> appending to the pre-existing list
>
> Current : Einstein
>
> Head : Albert

Here's init()

```
/*init()*/
Student* init(char* name)
{
    Student* currentp = (Student*)malloc(sizeof(Student));
    if (!currentp)
    {
        printf("pointer allocation problem..Ending the program...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    currentp->name = name;
    currentp->nextp = NULL;
    currentp->scoreHeadp = NULL;

   return currentp;
```

}

Comment: We need to see init() or know what it does: does it malloc a node, or return a static one? Does it malloc a copy of Name, or does it just store a pointer to it? If it doesn't give you a new node with a copy of name, you'll get the results you see.

Comment: added the init().This does a malloc..it stores pointer to the name.

Comment: Obligatory comment for a question tagged "C": don't cast the return value of `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same `char Name[30];` for every student.

Comment: More specifically, `currentp->name = name` is the offending line. You're assigning `currentp->name` to the same location in memory every time. Change it to something like `currentp->name = strdup(name)`. (This is assuming that `currentp->name` is a `char *`)

Comment: @user1589088 how you made your change ?

Comment: @silvesthu in main:I made Name[30] to Name[30][30]; then, I need not change anything but Name to Name[count]..

Comment: would you mind paste your modification here? I checked the code of linked-list it works well so I think the name string is only problem.

Comment: I'm sorry I have to go out now. Here's my test code. I wrote based on yours and it works well. http://ideone.com/eUxuy

Comment: @user1589088 Can you add the declaration of `Student`?

Comment: I think declaration of Student was included in my code. Or might you show me all your code somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your init function:

```
/*init()*/
Student* init(char* name)
{
    Student* currentp = (Student*)malloc(sizeof(Student));
    /* Allocate memory also for the student name */
    currentp->name = (char *)malloc(strlen(name) * sizeof(char));
    if (!currentp)
    {
        printf("pointer allocation problem..Ending the program...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    //currentp->name = name;
    strncpy(currentp->name, name, strlen(name));
    currentp->nextp = NULL;
    currentp->scoreHeadp = NULL;

   return currentp;
}
```